# Why does Fortran output have a leading space?

Tags: formatting, fortran, whitespace

I process lots of output from Fortran programs, and it generally appears that the output from these programs has a leading space, i.e., character column 1 is blank. Consider a short program `leading.f`:

```
      program leading
      print *, "<-- What's that space for?"
      end program leading
```

Has the output

```
 <-- What's that space for?
```

(yes, there is one space character at the beginning). My question is contained in the program.

Comment: Having no answer to what is it for, here's how to suppress it if you so desire: use string formatted output instead of unformatted one: `write(*,"(A)")"a space, really?"`

Comment: Best explained here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296237/are-fortran-control-characters-carriage-control-still-implemented-in-compilers

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Back in the dinosaur era, when FORTRAN output usually went to a green-bar impact printer, certain characters in the first print column were often interpreted as control codes (line feeds, form feeds, etc).  Many programmers learned to explicitly blank column 1 of their output, unless some special effect was intended -- and old habits die hard!

Answer (score 3):

As has been noted in another answer here, and elsewhere, Fortran output had the concept of *carriage control*.  For printers which used carriage control the first character being a blank was necessary for a new line to be started.

Fortran [itself deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3296237/3157076) carriage control concept in Fortran 2003, but for completeness we can see that Fortran still requires list-directed output to have (in most cases) this (default) leading blank (Fortran 2018, 13.10.4 p.13):

> Except for new records created by explicit formatting within a defined output procedure or by continuation of delimited character sequences, each output record begins with a blank character.

Namelist formatting has a similar statement.

You can avoid having this leading blank by avoiding using list-directed output:

```
print '(A)', '<-- No space here'
end
```

Note that it isn't the `print` here, but the list-directed output, which is to blame. We see similar with `write`:

```
write (*,*) '<-- Space from the list-directed output'
end
```

Finally, if we are using *internal files* we still get a leading blank with list-directed output:

```
character(len=20) :: internal
write (internal, *) '<-- Leading blank here'
end
```

(If we then output this internal file with list-directed output we'll see *two* leading blanks.)