# Fortran: How to avoid leading blank symbol during writing to a file

Tags: file, fortran, output

I need to write some data to a file and it is critical to have string started from the first column. But by default first column is blank.
Is there any ability to start string from the first column?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try taking control of the output with a format statement or a format string on your `write` statement(s).  For anything more helpful show us your code.

Comment: Related threads: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10627626/why-does-fortran-output-have-a-leading-space and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296237/are-fortran-control-characters-carriage-control-still-implemented-in-compilers

Comment: You can search "Fortran carriage control" to get relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

Solutions found:
write(100,**'(A)'**)