# Writing both characters and digits in an array

Tags: fortran

I have a Fortran code which reads a txt file with seperate lines of characters and digits and then write them in a 1D array with 20 elements.
This code is not compatible with Fortran 77 compiler Force 2.0.9. My question is that how we can apply the aformenetioned procedure using a Fortran 77 compiler;i.e defining a 1D array nd then write the txt file line by line into elements of the array?

Thank you in advance.

The txt file follows:

Case 1:

```
10  0  1  2  0

1.104  1.008  0.6   5.0

25  125.0  175.0  0.7  1000.0

0.60

1  5
```

Advanced Case

```
15 53 0 10 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0

0 0 1500.0 0 0 .03

0 0.001 0

0.1 0 0.125 0.08 0.46

0.1 5.0 0.04
```

@ Jason: 
I am a beginner and still learning Fortran. I guess Force 2 uses g77.
The followings are the correspond part of the original code. Force 2 editor returns an empty txt file as a result.

```
       DIMENSION CARD(20)
       CHARACTER*64 FILENAME
       DATA XHEND / 4HEND  /

       OPEN(UNIT=3,FILE='CON')
       OPEN(UNIT=4,FILE='CON')
       OPEN(UNIT=7,STATUS='SCRATCH')

       WRITE(3,9000) 'PLEASE ENTER THE INPUT FILE NAME : '
  9000 FORMAT (A)
       READ(4,9000) FILENAME

       OPEN(UNIT=5,FILE=FILENAME,STATUS='OLD')
       WRITE(3,9000) 'PLEASE ENTER THE OUTPUT FILE NAME : '
       READ(4,9000) FILENAME
       OPEN(UNIT=6,FILE=FILENAME,STATUS='NEW')
       FILENAME = '...'

       IR = 7
       IW = 6
       IP = 15
  5    REWIND IR
       I = 0
  2    READ (5,7204,END=10000) CARD
       IF (I .EQ. 0 ) WRITE (IW,7000)
  7000 FORMAT (1H1 / 10X,15HINPUT DECK ECHO / 10X,15(1H-))
       I= I + 1
       WRITE (IW,9204)  I,CARD
       IF (CARD(1) .EQ. XHEND ) GO TO 7020
       WRITE (IR,7204) CARD
  7204 FORMAT (20A4)
  9204 FORMAT (1X,I4,2X,20A4)
       GO TO 2
  7020 REWIND IR
```

Comment: Please post code. Also note that Force is not a compiler, but an editor. It is using either gfortran, g95 or g77. Do you know which one? Also, please post code.

Answer (score 4):

It looks that CARD is being used as a to hold 20 4-character strings.  I don't see the declaration as a character variable, only as an array, so perhaps in extremely old FORTRAN style a non-character variable is being used to hold characters?   You are using a 20A4 format, so the values have to be positioned in the file precisely as 20 groups of 4 characters.   You have to add blanks so that they are aligned into groups of 4 columns.

If you want to read numbers it would be much easier to read them into a numeric type and use list-directed IO:

```
real values (20)
read (5, *) values
```

Then you wouldn't have to worry about precision positioning of the values in the file.

This is really archaic FORTRAN ... even pre-FORTRAN-77 in style.  I can't remember the last time that I saw Hollerith (H) formats!  Where are you learning this from?

Edit: While I like Fortran for many programming tasks, I wouldn't use FORTRAN 66!  Computers are supposed to make things easier ... there is no reason to have to count characters.  Instead of

```
7000 FORMAT (1H1 / 10X,15HINPUT DECK ECHO / 10X,15(1H-))
```

You can use

```
7000 FORMAT ( / 10X, "INPUT DECK ECHO" / 10X, 15("-") )
```

I can think of only two reasons to use a Hollerith code: not bothering to change legacy source code (it is remarkable that a current Fortran compiler can process a feature that was obsolete 30 years ago!  Fortran source code never dies!), or studying the history of computing languages.  The name honors a great computing pioneer, whose invention accomplished the 1890 US Census in one year, when the 1880 Census took eight years: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herman_Hollerith

I much doubt that you will see the "1" in the first column performing "carriage control" today.  I had to look up that "1" was the code for page eject.  You are much more likely to see it in your output.   See [Are Fortran control characters (carriage control) still implemented in compilers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296237/are-fortran-control-characters-carriage-control-still-implemented-in-compilers)

Comment: I still routinely write f77 code (complete with `blockdata` and `equivalence` -- fortunately no `entry` though) due to external constraints (don't ask) and I've never seen a Hollerith format