# DATA declaration in Fortran

Tags: fortran

Does anyone know the meaning of 4HEND in the following line which comes from an old Fortran code?

DATA XHEND / 4HEND  /

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It replaces assignment

```
XHEND='END '
```

Comment: It doesn't always replace the assignment. Variables in subroutines and in functions, initialised with `DATA` statements, are also implicitly saved as if they were used in a `SAVE` statement.

Answer (score 5):

*4HEND* is a Hollerith code to represent the character string "END ".   In very old FORTRAN, the variable *XHEND* might even be a 4-byte integer or real used to hold character data.   If implicit typing was in effect in this program, XHEND would have been a real.   Another recent question with Hollerith codes: [Writing both characters and digits in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11695859/writing-both-characters-and-digits-in-an-array)