# what does DATA TKX/2HKX/ mean in fortran?

Tags: fortran

Such kind of data initialize in fortran:

```
DATA TKX/2HKX/
```

`TKX` is a double real number.
What does that mean?

Comment: Previous similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11855178/data-declaration-in-fortran

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DATA` is an old-fashioned way of initialising a variable and `2HKX` is an example of an (even more) old-fashioned Fortran feature called *Hollerith data*.  In this case `2HKX` is a way of expressing the string `KX` for a language without character or string data types; Fortran before FORTRAN77 was such a language.  So what you have is a way of storing the 2 character string `KX` in a variable declared to be of numeric (in your case `DOUBLE PRECISION`) type.

Hollerith data was dropped from the language in the 77 standard but, like all good (wink) things, has lingered long past its use-by date.