# End of Record error when saving a variable

Tags: fortran, runtime-error

I'm having a runtime error when I run a code that works without problems using a different computer.

I'm wondering if the problem is the Fortran compiler of this machine (GCC 4.9.2) since the former computer used a previous version.

The issue comes when defining a variable like this:

In a module I define

```
character(30),allocatable,save :: sceneclass(:)
```

Then in the subroutine `sceneclass` is defined according to

```
character(30) surf, frac, scene

allocate(sceneclass(10)) 

do i=1,10
write(sceneclass(i),*) trim(scene)//trim(surf)//'_'//trim(frac)
enddo
```

In the first iteration I get the "End of record". But I don't know where is the problem. It seems to work fine in other computers.

Comment: What is the value of `scene` `surf` and `frac`? It is possible you will have to create a fully compilable example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably writing a string to `sceneclass(i)` that is longer then the 30 chars you specified.

I can reproduce this with

```
program test
  implicit none
  character(10),allocatable :: sceneclass(:)
  integer                   :: i

  allocate( sceneclass(10) ) 

  do i=1,10
    write(sceneclass(i),*) 10**i
  enddo

  print *, ( trim(sceneclass(i)), i=1,10 )

end program
```

`gfortran` fails with

> Fortran runtime error: End of record

while `ifort` reports the error correctly:

> output statement overflows record, unit -5, file Internal List-Directed Write

Increasing the string length to 12 solves the issue in this case. You can (and should) use `iostat` within the `write` statement to capture this.

Comment: I created a [feature request/bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65684) at the GCC site.

Comment: That was the issue. For same reason, blanks weren't a problem using previous gcc fortran versions. Thanks!

Comment: @cardogar Blanks should not be a problem! BTW this is why I asked what is in those variables you write because it looked like an overflow. You should always supply complete information in your question. And I don't think the error message is wrong, it is more or less equivalent to the intel's one.

Comment: @VladimirF Probably, but it is misleading (in my eyes). Intel's error message directly leads to the cause of the problem.

Comment: I could imagine some compiler blindly over writing into whatever is adjacent in memory.  Could you be specific what old version accepted this?

Answer (score 1):

One thing to be aware of, when you specify a list directed `*` write of a character string, the compiler always(?) adds an extra lead blank, so the effective length of the string you can write is one less than you might expect.

To remedy that (and of course assuming you don't want the lead blank anyway ) use a string edit descriptor:

```
   write(sceneclass(i),'(a)')...
```

Interestingly `ifort` (linux 11.1)  actually allows you to overrun by one character:

```
 character*5 c
 write(c,*)'12345'  ! result: " 1234"
```

which I would consider a bug. It seems they forgot to count the blank too..  ( gfortran throws the above error on this, and ifort balks if you add one more character )

see here if you wonder why the blank.. [Are Fortran control characters (carriage control) still implemented in compilers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296237/are-fortran-control-characters-carriage-control-still-implemented-in-compilers)

and now I'm curious if some compiler somewhere didn't do that for an internal list write, or maybe your code was previously compiled with a flag to disable the "printer control" code